# Append to a nested list in a list of dicts under conditions

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

I have 2 lists that share information. First, I want to have a unique set of names (e.g.`list_person` has repeated `name` values); For this I produce a new list of dictionaries. *Then*, I want to add/append `list_pets['pet']` to the correct `list_person['pets']` in the new dictionary with unique name values, when the `list_pets['person_id']` matches the `list_person['id']`.

For clarification here is my code + desired output:

**My current code:**

```
list_person = [{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat']}, # you see that name values are repeated
              {'id': 678910, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['zebra']},
              {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse']},
              {'id': 141516, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['rabbit']}]

list_pets = [{'id': 'abcd', 'pet': 'shark', 'person_id': 12345}, #Bobby Bobs' pets
             {'id': 'efgh', 'pet': 'tiger', 'person_id': 678910}, #Bobby Bobs' pets
             {'id': 'ijkl', 'pet': 'elephant', 'person_id': 111213}, #Lisa Bobs' pets
             {'id': 'mnopq', 'pet': 'dog', 'person_id': 141516}] #Lisa Bobs' pets

output = []
for person, pet in zip(list_person, list_pets):
    t = [temp_dict['name'] for temp_dict in output]
    if person['name'] not in t:
        output.append(person)    # make a new list of dicts with unique name values
        for unique_person in output: # if they share ID, add the missing pets. 
            if person['id'] == pet['person_id']:
                unique_person['pets'].append(pet['pet'])
print(output)
```

**Desired output:**

```
desired_out = [{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat', 'zebra', 'shark', 'tiger']},
                {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse', 'rabbit', 'elephant', 'dog']}]
```

**Current output:**

```
[{'id': 12345, 'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'pets': ['cat', 'shark', 'elephant']}, {'id': 111213, 'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'pets': ['horse', 'elephant']}]
```

My current output is not displaying all the correct pets. Why is that; and what advice would one give to me to get closer to the solution?

Comment: What does your current code output?

Comment: I made an edit to the question with my current output. All of the code above is reproducible btw. :) thanks

Comment: Should id of output be the first occurrence for a name

Comment: This appears to be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).  You've used `dict`s where you should use a data frame; your IDs are not unique.  If you design this "properly", this is a simple data frame `merge` and a `groupby`.  Is there some system requirement that results in what appears to be poor design decisions?

Comment: @Rajesh C it doesn't have to be. The important thing is to have the name once in the list of dicts, and all the pets related to that person.  In other words, no info loss.

Comment: @Prune, if you could provide with an example with what you've just described I would appreciate it. In the end I do need a list of dicts, as I am dealing with Pysolr and populating a Solr database. The data I provide here is ofc made up for the question.

Comment: @Prune the id's ARE unique btw. In my real script I use UUID (btw). Some of the ID's link between different list of dictionaries as a way of linking information

Comment: You label those as `person_id`, but you have multiple IDs for each person.  Thus, they are not unique as labeled.

Comment: "Provide me an example" is out of scope for Stack Overflow, as such generic examples exist in almost any tutorial on PANDAS data frames.

Comment: Is there any guarantee of order connection between `list_person` and `list_pets`? Bobby has the first two records in both `list_person` and `list_pets`, or is that just a coincidence in the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a non-pandas solution, and it doesn't rely on an order-relation between `list_person` (aka 'people') and `list_pets`. So I'm not assuming that Bobby's data is the first two entries in both lists.

Initially, `output` will be a mapping on names to the person's data, incl pets. And `ids` will be maintained to link each person's different IDs - by intentionally using a reference to the data dict and not a copy.

Note that when a person is added to `output`, it is done as a *deepcopy* so that it doesn't affect the original item in `list_person`.

```py
import copy

output = {}  # dict, not list
ids = {}  # needed to match with pets which has person_id

for person in list_person:
    if (name := person['name']) in output:
        output[name]['pets'].extend(person['pets'])
        output[name]['id'].append(person['id'])
        ids[person['id']] = output[name]  # itentionally a reference, not a copy
    else:
        output[name] = copy.deepcopy(person)  # so that the pet list is created as a copy
        output[name]['id'] = [output[person['name']]['id']]  # turn id's into a list
        ids[person['id']] = output[name]  # itentionally a reference, not a copy

for pet in list_pets:
    # the values in ids dict can be references to the same object
    # so use that to our advantage by directly appending to 'pet' list
    ids[pet['person_id']]['pets'].append(pet['pet'])
```

`output` is now:

```py
{'Bobby Bobs': {'id': [12345, 678910],
                'name': 'Bobby Bobs',
                'pets': ['cat', 'zebra', 'shark', 'tiger']},
 'Lisa Bobs': {'id': [111213, 141516],
               'name': 'Lisa Bobs',
               'pets': ['horse', 'rabbit', 'elephant', 'dog']}
}
```

Final step to make it a list and only use one `id` for each person:

```py
output = list(output.values())
for entry in output:
    entry['id'] = entry['id'][0]  # just the first id
```

Final `output`:

```py
[{'id': 12345,
  'name': 'Bobby Bobs',
  'pets': ['cat', 'zebra', 'shark', 'tiger']},
 {'id': 111213,
  'name': 'Lisa Bobs',
  'pets': ['horse', 'rabbit', 'elephant', 'dog']}]
```

And if you don't mind multiple ids, skip the last step above and leave it at `output = list(output.values())`.

Comment: really nicely explained and very readable. Learnt a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
person_df = pd.DataFrame(list_person)
pets_df = pd.DataFrame(list_pets).drop(columns = ['id'])
joined_df = person_df.merge(pets_df, left_on = ['id'], right_on = ['person_id'])
```

Joined df:

```
>>> joined_df
       id        name               pets       pet  person_id
0   12345  Bobby Bobs       [cat, shark]     shark      12345
1  678910  Bobby Bobs     [zebra, tiger]     tiger     678910
2  111213   Lisa Bobs  [horse, elephant]  elephant     111213
3  141516   Lisa Bobs      [rabbit, dog]       dog     141516
```

Now first combine pets and pet columns then groupby on name

```
joined_df['pets'] = [pets + [pet] for pets, pet in zip(joined_df['pets'], joined_df['pet'])]
final_list = joined_df.groupby('name', as_index = False).agg(
                                  id = ('id', 'first'), 
                                  pets = ('pets', lambda x: list(itertools.chain(*x)))
                                ).to_dict('records')
```

Output:

```
>>> final_list
 [{'name': 'Bobby Bobs', 'id': 12345, 'pets': ['cat', 'shark', 'zebra', 'tiger']}, 
{'name': 'Lisa Bobs', 'id': 111213, 'pets': ['horse', 'elephant', 'rabbit', 'dog']}]
```